# <?php echo base_url();?> and <?php base_url();?>

Tags: php

```
 <script src='<?php base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

the script above is code that my friend use, that works just for him, but if i change it to `<?php echo base_url();?>` and it's work for me, not for him. 
It's become a problem when we transfer files each other, What i am supposed to do ?
thank you.

---

I've solution script for my case, change this from config.php :
`$http = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$urlbaru = str_replace("index.php","", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']    = "$http" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "" . $urlbaru;`

Comment: Maybe you're not using the same PHP version as he is? The (); one should be right tho if it's a function.

Comment: *"It's become a problem when we transfer files each other"* Perhaps you don't have the same base urls

Comment: Well, `base_url()` is not a built-in function to begin with.

Comment: `base_dir()` isn't a built in PHP function, you're probably using a framework function which could explain the difference.

Comment: I use PHP version 5.5.30 and he said he use same php version. @Janno

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález @paradoxis @hd thankyou, i think he use wrong url, he use `http://localhost/site/` only, so it will work if use `base_url();` because base_url() without echo won't display anyting, like `<?php echo base_url();?>assets\css\file.css` it will output only \assets\css\file.css not the full part of the url. i will tell him as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show more about your problem detail like paste your error code in here that we could use those information to help you.

Btw, base_url() isn't a php embedded function, one of the potential problem is that your friend custom a function named base_url() that supposed to return it's root path.
So, you have to either include or build the same function with the same name to your script.

Ex.

```
function base_url()
{
  return dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
}
```

And the 'src' inside your  tag should point to your jQuery source file.

Comment: he only said to me that the code display blank page. i should ask him further information of the error. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using codeigniter framwork, and you have not autoloaded URL helper, that's why you getting error. if I am not wrong you have to load URL helper.

Comment: i have load it before.
`$autoload['helper'] = array('url','html','form','file','text','directory','date','xml');`