# How to add favicon image on browser title bar in website

Tags: html, css, browser, icons

I am trying this code

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>dist/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
```

this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Some more context would be useful to help solve this.
Looks like you're using a framework or custom code as `base_url` isn't a standard PHP method. [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631644/php-echo-base-url-and-php-base-url/38632454#38632454)
Also standardly; browsers expect favicon files to live in the public root of a project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot "/"

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/dist/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
```